# mongodb combine two documents from aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am new to the aggregation pipeline and tried to solve the following problem but could not. I have the following in my final $project stage.

```
{
"$project": {
  "_id": "$_id",
  "LICNENSE_NUMBER": "$LICNENSE_NUMBER",
  "FIRST_NAME": "$FIRST_NAME",
  "CREATED_DATE": "$CREATED_DATE",
  "SUBMITTED_DATE": "$SUBMITTED_DATE",
  "REOPENED_DATE": "$REOPENED_DATE",
  "APPROVED_DATE": "$APPROVED_DATE",
  "STATUS": "$STATUS",
  
  "Q1":   {
        $cond: {
           if: { $eq: [ "", "$Q1" ] },
           then: "$$REMOVE",
           else: "$Q1"
        }
     },
  "Q2": {
        $cond: {
           if: { $eq: [ "", "$Q2" ] },
           then: "$$REMOVE",
           else: "$Q2"
        }
     },
  
   }
}
```

The following is the results of the aggregation. [image]As you could see the two documents are identical apart from Q1 and Q2 fields and I just need to produce one document which has both the Q1 and Q2 fields without other duplicated fields. i.e. with, "_id", "LICNENSE_NUMBER", "FIRST_NAME", "CREATED_DATE", "SUBMITTED_DATE", "REOPENED_DATE", "APPROVED_DATE", "STATUS" fields **along with "Q1" and "Q2"** Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: HI, can you add the all pipeline and schema?

Comment: Group by unique key.